# Using define in simple sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way of defining a section of SQL as a constant for repeated use in a simple oracle SQL statement. In a similar way that can be done in a script and in a similar way to the WITH statement?

Something like

```
Define meat as "foodtype<>'fruit' and foodtype<>'veg'"

select * from meals where meat
```

Comment: Simply use `DEFINE` in `SQL*Plus`. See my answer.

Comment: My question was could this be done without using SQL*Plus

Comment: You did not mention that in your question. Anyway, yes you could do it in `PL/SQL` as I have shown in my answer. But, in plain `SQL`, NO.

Comment: Where are you running the query from - another client, or from an application? If the latter maybe your application can just manipulate the query string before executing, in Java, C, PHP, even a shell script, etc.?

Comment: My aim is to set up a view which my application can use. If the facility does not exist in plain SQL I thought it would be a relatively simple and useful extension which maybe oracle could consider in the future.

Answer (score 1):

In `SQL*Plus` you could use `DEFINE`.

For example,

```
SQL> define l_str = 'ename = ''SCOTT'''
SQL>
SQL> select empno, deptno from emp where &l_str;
old   1: select empno, deptno from emp where &l_str
new   1: select empno, deptno from emp where ename = 'SCOTT'

     EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ----------
      7788         20

SQL>
```

**NOTE** `DEFINE` is a `SQL*Plus` command. Define sets a user variable or displays its value.

However, not possible in plain `SQL` as the query won't `parse` and would throw an error. Since, during parse time, Oracle would expect it to be `static`, you cannot have it `dynamic`.

You can use `Dynamic SQL` in `PL/SQL`, such that you could have it as a `string variable` and use it repeatedly in the scope of the session.

For example,

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    var_str  VARCHAR2(1000);
  3    var_str1 VARCHAR2(1000);
  4    v_empno emp.empno%type;
  5  BEGIN
  6    var_str  := 'ename = ''SCOTT''';
  7    var_str1 := 'select empno FROM emp WHERE '|| var_str;
  8    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var_str1 INTO v_empno;
  9
 10    dbms_output.put_line(v_empno);
 11
 12  END;
 13  /
7788

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I don't need it to be dynamic. I envisage that the first thing that would happen on running the query would be equivalent of search and replace based on the define statement.

Comment: You can use the string variable wherever you need in the procedure scope.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question it seems that the condition should be dynamic. It can be acheived in `PLSQL` Block like below

```
DECLARE
  v1 varchar2(100) := ' foodtype <> ''fruit'' and foodtype <> ''Veg''';
  mealstyp meals%ROWTYPE; 
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from meals where'||v1 into mealstyp; 
  LOOP
    --your type record
  END LOOP;
END
```